# How do I declare model attributes in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to understand Rails and I dont understand how I declare the model attributes correctly. For now my user class is looking like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users # Friends
end
```

By Googling I have understand that before Rails 4 one could determine attributes with the attr_accessible, like this:

```
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :age, :sex
```

But this seems to be deprecated, how can I do that same thing in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :users` is not a model attribute, its [model association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It means model `User` can have many `User` objects, which is incorrect. (also does not make sense even literally)

**What [`attr_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_protected/class) does?**

> Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via
>   mass-assignmen

[To add attributes to a model, you need to generate migrations.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration)

Example, lets add name attribute to users:

```
rails generate migration AddNameToUsers  #creates a migration file to add `name` column to `users` table
```

followed by:

```
rake db:migrate  # executes migration file creating `name` column in `users` table
```

Now you can access these attributes simply as:

```
user = User.new
user.name
```

Again, if you want to mass-assign this attribute at some point of your code, you will need to specify this in your class with `attr_accessible`, as in your original example.